url invalid in appwrite and React+vite
Appwrite serive :: getCurrentUser :: error TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URLenter image description here
due to which not able to login or signup as you can see it in the given images [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/F0k4oAsV.png)

Sorry I can't get your problem. Can you explain your problem a little bit?
